# Maven : cannot find the tag library descriptor

Tags: tomcat, maven, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm using maven3 and tomcat7 , i want to use JSTL in my jsp page so i added this taglib:

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

the problem that i get this error message :cannot find the tag library descriptor
this is the dependencies added :
            
          javax.servlet
           jstl
           1.1.1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

i tried this taglib but the same problem persist :

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Have you an idea please

Answer (score 1):

You need two different jar files for tags to work. You have listed standard as a dependency, but you will also need to add a dependency for JSTL.

Comment: i added it but the problem persist

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer will help new one's searching on the same topic.. as I did and did not find any answers.. finally I fixed it ..

There are few steps to follow.. For Tomcat 7 and maven , jstl 1.2 & standard 1.1.0 is compatible

Update pom.xml file to

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>jstl</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Update web.xml file to

```
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns /j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

This Works!